# Convert a (nested)HTML unordered list of links to PHP array of links

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

I have a regular, nested HTML unordered list of links, and I'd like to scrape it with PHP and convert it to an array.

The original list looks something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://someurl.com">First item</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://someotherurl.com/">Child of First Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://someotherurl.com/">Second Child of First Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://bogusurl.com">Second item</a></li>
<li><a href="http://bogusurl.com">Third item</a></li>
<li><a href="http://bogusurl.com">Fourth item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any of the items can have children.

(The actual screen scraping is not a problem, I can do that.)

I'd like to turn this into a PHP array, of just the links, while keeping the hierarchical nature of the list. Any ideas?

I've looked at using htmlsimpledom and phpQuery, which both use jQuery like syntax. But, I can't seem to get the syntax right. I can get all the links, but I end up losing the hierarchical nature and order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMDocument and SimpleXMLElement along the lines of:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xmlStr = $doc->saveXml($doc->documentElement);

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($xmlStr);

$links = array();

foreach ($xml->xpath('//a') as $li) {
    $links[] = $li->attributes()->href;
}
```

If href is being added to $links as a SimpleXMLElement, use ob_start and ob_clean to capture the string.

[Cheat sheet for xpath queries](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/XSLT_1quickref-v2.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: Thanks, this gets all the links, but it loses the nesting!

Comment: There will be a way to do it using SimpleXmlElement but I can't answer off the top of my head. Try taking a look at the PHP manual for the class.