# get contents from another page using php?

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure this is possible or not.
I want a php script when executed , it will go to a page (on a different domain) and get the html contents of it and inside the html there's links , and that script is able to get each link's href.

html code:

```
<div id="somediv">
  <a href="http://yahoo.com" class="url">Yahoo</a>
  <a href="http://google.com" class="url">Google</a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com" class="url">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

The output code(which php will echo out) will be
http://yahoo.com
http://google.com
http://facebook.com

I have heard of cURL in php can do something like this but not exactly like this , i'm a bit confused , i hope some can guide me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some code that you can show us?

Comment: no sorry currently i dont even know which php function can do this or there is no way to do it.

Comment: You need to combine [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for things like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a web scraper in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947/how-to-implement-a-web-scraper-in-php)

Comment: You can use jQuery and Ajax to load the page you want. You don't need Php for this, as it should run on the client

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a (nested)HTML unordered list of links to PHP array of links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617487/convert-a-nestedhtml-unordered-list-of-links-to-php-array-of-links), There are lots of similar questions to yours, this one has a small code example how you can do that (not the best one, but it should work).

Answer (score 3):

have a look at something like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Using DOM and XPath:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://www.example.com/"); // or you could load from a string using loadHTML();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='somediv']//a");
foreach($elements as $elem){
    echo $elem->getAttribute('href');
}
```

BTW: you should read up on DOM and XPath.